# Why when I assign an int to a float is it not the same value?

Tags: java

When I assign from an int to a float I thought float allows more precision, so would not lose or change the value assigned, but what I am seeing is something quite different. What is going on here?

```
for(int i = 63000000; i < 63005515; i++) { 
   int a = i;
   float f = 0; 
   f=a; 
   System.out.print(java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance().format(a) + " : " );
   System.out.println(java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance().format(f));
}
```

some of the output :

...

63,005,504 : 63,005,504

63,005,505 : 63,005,504

63,005,506 : 63,005,504

63,005,507 : 63,005,508

63,005,508 : 63,005,508

Thanks!

Comment: Floats have limited precision. `float` refers to 32-bit values, of which a decent part is the exponent.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `float` has the same number of bits as an `int` -- 32 bits.  But it allows for a greater range of values, far greater than the range of `int` values.  However, the precision is fixed at 24 bits (23 "mantissa" bits, plus 1 implied `1` bit).  At the value of about 63,000,000, the precision is greater than `1`.  You can verify this with the [`Math.ulp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-float-) method, which gives the difference between 2 consecutive values.

The code

```
System.out.println(Math.ulp(63000000.0f));
```

prints

```
4.0
```

You can use `double` values for a far greater (yet still limited) precision:

```
System.out.println(Math.ulp(63000000.0));
```

prints

```
7.450580596923828E-9
```

However, you can just use `int`s here, because your values, at about 63 million, are still well below the maximum possible `int` value, which is about 2 billion.

Answer (score 2):

A float in java is a number IEEE 754 floating point representation, even when it can be used to represent values from ±1.40129846432481707e-45 to ±3.40282346638528860e+38 it has only 6 or 7 significant decimal digits.

A simple solution would be use a double which has at least 14 significant digits and can cover without any issue all the values of an int.

However, if it is accuracy what you're looking for stay away from native floating point representations and go for classes like BigInteger and BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not necessarily the same value.  An int and a float are each 32 bits but in a float some of those bits are used for the floating point part of the number so there are fewer whole numbers which can be represented in a float than in an int.  Depending on what your application is doing with these numbers you may not care about these differences or maybe you want to look at using something like BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

Floats don't allow more precision, floats allow wider range of numbers.

We've got 2^32 possible values for integers in range (approximately) -2 * 10^9 to 2 * 10^9. Floats are also 32bit, so the number of possible values is at most the same as for integers.

Out of these 32 bits, some of them are reserved for *mantisa*, the rest of these is for *exponent*. The resulting number represented by the float is then calculated (for simplicity I'll use 10-base) as `mantisa * 10^exponent`.

Obviously, the maximum *precision* is limited by the number of bits assigned to *mantisa*. So you can represent some integers exactly as integers, but they won't fit to mantisa, so the least significant bits are thrown off, as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

`Float` have a greater range of values but lower precision.

`Int` have a lower range of values but higher precision.

Int is specific to 1, while Float is specific to 4.

So if you are dealing with trillions but don't care about +/- 4 then use float. but if you need the last digit to be precise you need to use int.